# Graph plotting with arrays calculated by code

Tags: android, arrays, plot

I'm trying to make an application that can generate an XY chart from values calculated by code.

Basically I have 6 series to plot on a chart. I followed the [androidplot tutorial](https://github.com/halfhp/androidplot/blob/master/docs/quickstart.md?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=177)

But in the end, when I tried to plot the X-axis of the chart, I had difficulty in how I would do it. Could you give me some guidance, please? I really do not know how to do this even following the tutorial.

I want to point out that the code consists of: user data input, from this data the program performs several calculations and generate arrays. I would like to plot these arrays.

```
Arrays: (
    Momento_dominio1(), 
    Normal_dominio1()
), (
    Momento_dominio2(), 
    Normal_dominio2()
),(
    Momento_dominio3(), 
    Normal_dominio3()
)
```

Each of them are in public double and return an array.

**Code**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_resultado);

        graph = (XYPlot) findViewById(R.id.graph);

        XYSeries dominio1 = new SimpleXYSeries(Arrays.asList(this.Momento_Dominio1()), Arrays.asList(this.Normal_Dominio1()), "Domínio 1");
        XYSeries dominio2 = new SimpleXYSeries(Arrays.asList(this.Momento_Dominio2()), Arrays.asList(this.Normal_Dominio2()), "Domínio 2");
        XYSeries dominio3 = new SimpleXYSeries(Arrays.asList(this.Momento_Dominio3()), Arrays.asList(this.Normal_Dominio3()), "Domínio 3");

        LineAndPointFormatter dominio1Format = new LineAndPointFormatter(Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, null);
        LineAndPointFormatter dominio2Format = new LineAndPointFormatter(Color.GREEN, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, null);
        LineAndPointFormatter dominio3Format = new LineAndPointFormatter(Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, null);

        dominio1Format.getLinePaint().setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[] {
                PixelUtils.dpToPix(10),
                PixelUtils.dpToPix(10)}, 0));

        dominio2Format.getLinePaint().setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[] {
                PixelUtils.dpToPix(10),
                PixelUtils.dpToPix(10)}, 0));

        dominio3Format.getLinePaint().setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[] {
                PixelUtils.dpToPix(10),
                PixelUtils.dpToPix(10)}, 0));


        dominio1Format.setInterpolationParams(new CatmullRomInterpolator.Params(10, CatmullRomInterpolator.Type.Centripetal));
        dominio2Format.setInterpolationParams(new CatmullRomInterpolator.Params(10, CatmullRomInterpolator.Type.Centripetal));
        dominio3Format.setInterpolationParams(new CatmullRomInterpolator.Params(10, CatmullRomInterpolator.Type.Centripetal));

        graph.addSeries(dominio1, dominio1Format);
        graph.addSeries(dominio2, dominio2Format);
        graph.addSeries(dominio3, dominio3Format);
        }
```

**Following are the publics I used to compute Momento_dominio1 and Normal_dominio1 (this applies to others, Momento_dominio2, Momento_dominio3, Normal_dominio2 and Normal_dominio3)**

```
public double Normal_Dominio1() {

        angulo_variavel_dominio1 = 0;

        for (i=0; i<100; i++){

            Normal_dominio1 = this.Normal_Aco_Compressao_Dominio1() + this.Normal_Aco_Tracao_Dominio1(); // Como ambos estão em tração, o sinal é positivo

            Normal_vetor_dominio1[i] = Normal_dominio1; // O for é composto por 100 passadas, logo, cada passada deve ser salvo em uma parte do vetor

            angulo_variavel_dominio1 = angulo_variavel_dominio1 + (this.Angulo_Dominio1_Secao() / 100);

        }

        return Normal_vetor_dominio1[i];

    }


public double Momento_Dominio1() {

        angulo_variavel_dominio1 = 0;

        for (i=0; i<100; i++){

                Momento_dominio1 = -this.Momento_Aco_Compressao_Dominio1() + this.Momento_Aco_Tracao_Dominio1(); // Como ambos estão em tração, o sinal é positivo

                Momento_vetor_dominio1[i] = Momento_dominio1; // O for é composto por 100 passadas, logo, cada passada deve ser salvo em uma parte do vetor

                angulo_variavel_dominio1 = angulo_variavel_dominio1 + (this.Angulo_Dominio1_Secao() / 100);

        }

        return Momento_vetor_dominio1[i];

    }
```

Comment: I'm having a little trouble understanding the specific nature of the problem, but sounds like maybe you're struggling with how to include xVals along with your yVals?

Comment: Exact! The part of tracing the X axis is given at the top of the code, as far as I understand.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're only including your yVals when you setup each series:

```
XYSeries dominio1 = new SimpleXYSeries(
    Arrays.asList(this.Momento_Dominio1()),
    SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY, 
    "Domínio 1");
```

The `SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY` argument tells Androidplot to automatically generate xVals using the index (iVal) of each yVal.  To include your own xVals you'd instantiate `SimpleXYSeries` like this instead:

```
XYSeries dominio1 = new SimpleXYSeries(
    Arrays.asList(yourXValsArray),
    Arrays.asList(yourYValsArray),
    "Domínio 1");
```

The SimpleXYSeries section of [this doc](https://github.com/halfhp/androidplot/blob/master/docs/xyplot.md) has more detail if you need it.

Comment: Good. I did this, but I do not know why it gave the error "Can not interpolate a series with fewer than 3 vertices." Do you know what it can be?

Comment: You'll get this error when your XYSeries has two or fewer values in it and you enable interpolation.  If you remove your calls to `setInterpolationParams` then the error should go away.

Comment: Sorry, the error still persists. I'm doing something wrong in something .... I'll update the code here and you could look, Nick? I'm already abusing your goodwill, but I'm not really identifying.